# What did Naizer mean by Creed's sword being "alien"?

Tags: black-cat

When Train was fighting Sephiria Arks on top of the construction site, Creed was watching from the alleyway, where he was confronted by Nizer Bruckheimer and Ash.

After Creed killed Ash, Nizer commented that he wouldn't be done away by a "invisible sword", because he could see the sword, with it coated in Ash's blood. Creed's sword extended, striking Nizer but failing to kill him.

When Nizer was struck, he said:

> We don't use that alien technique in Chronos

which I assume he was referring to Creed's sword, but what did he mean by *alien*?

This is from the English dubbed version by Madman.

Comment: Please point out which language version you're referring to. Not all localizations are created equal.

Comment: This is probably not related to anime at all, but I think what Nizer meant by "alien" is "something that's unrecognizable/not exist on their culture". Note that "[alien](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/alien)" has several meaning other than the common "creature from outer space" (now, I don't watch the show, so I don't know about the context)